# How to export Japanese characters from SQL Server 2008 database to a text file?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an odd problem. I need to export Japanese characters from a table to a raw text file.  When I run the select statement in SQL, I am able to see the characters displayed correctly.  However, when I run the SSIS package to export these values to a text file they are displayed as **`?`**'s.

Data type of the field is *NTEXT*. Has anyone ran into this problem before?

*SQL statement*:

```
select cast(body as nvarchar(max)) as body from msgsMarket
```

In SSIS package's flat file connection manager, I have set the output encoding to use **`932`**

Comment: What encoding are you writing out the files as?

Comment: [Asp.net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1324009.aspx/1)
Those functions should still be valid and as @Oded stated its all about the encoding.

Comment: @Oded Please see edit, i am able to extract them successfully when i run the query as 'save results to text', but i need to run this as an automated process

Comment: What happens if you use UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: @Oded If i do that in ssis i get close, the result is something like this:   _x003C_none_x003E_あいよ_x003C_none_x003E_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solution but might probably help you to identify the problem in your case.

Created a sample SSIS package using SSIS 2008 R2 with `UTF-8` and `Unicode` encodings and the SQL Server data exported correctly to flat files.

Sample SQL data in the file. *Description* field was of data type *`NVARCHAR`*. The sample was also tried by changing the data type of the Description field to *`NTEXT`* and the flat files still exported correctly.

[image: Sample SQL data]

SSIS package was created with a data flow task with two outputs for *UTF-8* and *Unicode*.

[image: Data flow task]

First flat file connection manager to generate flat file with encoding *UTF-8*.

[image: UTF-8 encoding]

Output file generated with *UTF-8* encoding.

[image: UTF-8 output file]

Second flat file connection manager to generate flat file with encoding *Unicode*.

[image: Unicode encoding]

Output file generated with *Unicode* encoding.

[image: Unicode output file]